# Why the getItem method of Local Storage object has been used before setItem in following JS code?

Tags: javascript, dom, local-storage

https://github.com/john-smilga/javascript-basic-projects/blob/master/14-grocery-bud/final/app.js#L6

The following code has been written from the above link. Full Version of this code is in the link. My question is why getItem method is used before setting Item and what is the logic the behind this?

Thanks.

```
function addToLocalStorage(id, value) {
  const grocery = { id, value };
  let items = getLocalStorage();
  items.push(grocery);
  localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(items));
}

function getLocalStorage() {
  return localStorage.getItem("list")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"))
    : [];
}
``
```

Comment: one needs to read the current value to add to it, rather than replace the value

Comment: is “Hoisting” for the answer？ it is a javascript language features

Comment: @binliu - absolutely nothing to do with hoisting

Comment: oh， do you want to say why you can get items in the addToLocalStorage? because if it is not exsist; you can get an empty array []

Answer (score 1):

Because the intent behind the code is to add an item to an array in localstorage. You fetch the array, or create a new one if it doesn't exist. You push an item onto it and then save it back to localstorage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have understood the point. Now my concept is clear. :)